# How to set default countries and show respected states in countries.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Countries.js to populate countries and states to a website. I need to set default a country on load and show respective states in select state input. How can it be done?

I have tried Couple of things from the internet.

1.

```js
<script>populateCountries("us", "state");</script>;
```

2.
In Core file -->

```js
if (stateElementId) {
  countryElement.onchange = function() {
    populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
    //populateStates( "us", stateElementId );
  };
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: No. I am not able to solve the problem still.

Comment: Have you tried the answers provided

Comment: Yes I have marked an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a default country `onload`, first populate the countries `select` element with countries using the `load` document event listener, then get the country `select` element object by id e.g. `countryElement`. Using that, set the value to a default country e.g. 'USA', and trigger `onchange()` on the element to populate the states `select` box. The below example does this, and then triggers a new country selection after 5 seconds to showcase further the state `select` box changing.. You selected `jQuery` tag for this question, but I didn't see any `jQuery` in your example so I kept it to straight vanilla JS for the example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  populateCountries("country", "state");

  $countryElement = $('#country');
  $stateElement = $('#state');

  $countryElement.val('USA').trigger('change');
  $stateElement.val('Florida');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $countryElement.val('American Samoa').trigger('change');
    $stateElement.val('Eastern');
  }, 5000);

});

/*

document.addEventListener("load",
  populateCountries("country", "state")
);

var countryElement = document.getElementById('country');
var stateElement = document.getElementById('state');

// Set default country
countryElement.value = 'USA';
// Triggers state select population..
countryElement.onchange();
// Set state for country selected..
stateElement.value = 'Florida';

// 5 seconds later, select a different country..
setTimeout(function() {
  countryElement.value = 'American Samoa';
  countryElement.onchange();
  stateElement.value = 'Eastern';
}, 5000);

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-toggle-group="location">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" data-toggle="country" data-country=""></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>State</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state" data-toggle="state" data-state=""></select>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/generic-country-state-dropdown-list-countries-js/countries.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did this end up working for you? Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: This Is Working Fine.. Thanks for this solution. Just one question - How can I implement this to normal jQuery, What I am using now.

Comment: Updated the answer to include jQuery solution as well. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Jquery document ready function like below. But you have to include the jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    populateCountries("us", "state");
});
</script>
```

you can see the more detail here at below link.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Then it should be issue of populateCountries function. can you share that function? specially key and value pair is required to check.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it right by setting its value:

```
$('select').val('stateElementId')
```

or by the text inside the `<option></option>`

```
$('select option:contains("us")').prop('selected',true);
```